# Escape hash mark (#) in /etc/environment

Tags: environment-variables, login, pam

I am adding an env variable to `/etc/environment` but because the variable value contains # sign, string is stripped.

```
MYSQL_PWD="something#no"
```

Now if I do `env` above code yields `MYSQL_PWD=something`. How can I escape hash? I've already tried `\` character.

Comment: Are you sure you're posting the exact same thing you're putting in `/etc/environment`? Because I couldn't duplicate this behavior on Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Sorry export is not there. Updated my question.

Comment: For now I have changed MySQL pwd :(

Comment: I managed to duplicate your behavior. I didn't realize I needed to log out then back in to get my shell to read `/etc/environment`.

Comment: @JosephR. - I duplicated this and was surprised as well. Looking into the role of this file it seems to be consistent with it's intent.

Comment: @slm You're right of course. Great answer!

Comment: @JosephR. - thanks. I can't believe this works like this, I never used this file before today so now I know why 8-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible with `/etc/environment`. It's meant as a common location for variables that's shell independent. Given this it doesn't look like it supports strings with hash marks (`#`) in them and there doesn't appear to be a way to escape them.

I found this SF Q&A titled: [How does one properly escape a leading “#” character in linux etc/environment?](https://serverfault.com/questions/506053/how-does-one-properly-escape-a-leading-character-in-linux-etc-environment). None of these methods worked:

- control="hello"
- test0="#hello"
- test1="h\#ello"
- test2="h#ello"
- test3="h//#ello"
- test4="h/#ello"
- test5=h#ello
- test6=h\#ello
- test7=h#ello
- test8=h//#ello
- test9=h/#ello
- test10='h#ello'
- test11='h\#ello'
- test12='h#ello'
- test13='h//#ello'
- test14='h/#ello'

The accepted answer to that question and what would also be my advice:

> Well it is tricky stuff you want to do `/etc/environment` is not shell syntax, it looks like one , but it is not, which does frustrates people. The idea behind `/etc/environment` was wonderful. A shell-independent way to set up variables! Yay! But the practical limitations make it useless.
>
> You can't pass variables in there. Try for example put `MAIL=$HOME/Maildir/` into it and see what happens. Best just to stop trying to use it for any purpose whatsoever, alas. So you can't do things with it that you would expect to be able to do if it were processed by a shell.
>
> Use `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`.

Yet still [another Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/539730/environment-variable-in-etc-environment-with-pound-hash-sign-in-the-value) gave this rational as to why this is the case:

> There is no way in `/etc/environment` to escape the #(as it treated as a comment) as it is being parsed by he PAM module "pam_env" and it treats it as a simple list of KEY=VAL pairs and sets up the environment accordingly. It is not bash/shell, the parser has no language for doing variable expansion or characters escaping.

#### References

- [Environment variable in /etc/environment with pound (hash) sign in the value](https://serverfault.com/questions/539730/environment-variable-in-etc-environment-with-pound-hash-sign-in-the-value)

Comment: is that a bug or there's any reason behind it?

Comment: @UmairAshraf - not a bug, just limited functionality given the role of this file. This file spans across multiple shell technologies so it has to go with features that are supported in all the shells it will be used in.

Comment: It might be useful to add information regarding pam_env.conf file. It is read right before /etc/environment by pam, and as suggested by the man page of pam_env.conf (that documents the use of both these files) can use variables and some for of escaping.

Answer (score 5):

Single quote within a double quote worked for me. Might help someone

```
test="'h/#ello'"
```

Comment: this does not work on debian

Comment: This solutions worked great in my Laravel .env file!

Comment: worked without the / on bash - just `h#ello`

Comment: Works great on mac/unix

Answer (score 0):

Testing with NodeJS (specifically in an Express app), if the variable contains reserved characters, you can put the entire variable in quotation marks.

```
EXAMPLE_VAR = he#llo
FIXED_EXAMPLE_VAR = "he#llo"
```

Then trying to use the variables:

```
console.log(process.env.EXAMPLE_VAR); // outputs `he`
console.log(process.env.FIXED_EXAMPLE_VAR); // outputs `he#llo`
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably too late, but **three backslashes** before `#` worked for me.

If the password is, say "admin#123",
you can define it as

```
admin\\\#123
```

Comment: This did not work for me in the `/etc/environment` file.

Comment: this does not work on debian

Answer (score -1):

Replace `#` with `%23`.

For example from:

```
postgres://user:#password#@server:port/database
```

To:

```
DB_URI="postgres://user:%23password%23@server:port/database"
```