# tar not working with sudo

Tags: tar, gzip

I am trying to extract a file into `/usr/local/` using

```bash
$ sudo tar -xvzf /home/vyom/Downloads/go1.19.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

But when I change the directory to which I have access to (eg - `/home/vyom/abc`) it works perfectly fine

```bash
$ tar -xvzf /home/vyom/Downloads/go1.19.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /home/vyom/abc
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/7.dir/b.go
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/7.go
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/8.dir/
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/8.dir/a.go
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/8.dir/b.go
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/8.go
go/test/typeparam/mdempsky/9.go
go/test/typeparam/metrics.go
go/test/typeparam/min.go
....
```

`gzip` is also not missing

```bash
$ gzip --version
gzip 1.12
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1993 Jean-loup Gailly.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Jean-loup Gailly.
```

EDIT:

**After getting some input about `secure_path`, I checked it:**

```bash
$ echo $PATH
/home/vyom/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-17.0.5.0.8-1.fc37.x86_64/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

```bash
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep "secure_path"
Defaults    secure_path = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

The secure path contains all `*/bin` folders, but the command starts to work when I use `-E env "PATH=$PATH"` with `sudo`.

```bash
$ sudo sudo -V | grep "Value to override user's"                                  
Value to override user's $PATH with: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

Relevant content from `/etc/sudoers`

```
Defaults   !visiblepw

Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    match_group_by_gid

Defaults    always_query_group_plugin

Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

Defaults    secure_path = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
```

What is the problem over here?

Comment: Adding `-E env "PATH=$PATH"` flag to `sudo` makes it work but how is this happening, I am a bit confused.

Comment: It perhaps indicates that the default sudoers policy is setting the `PATH` equal to its `secure_path`, and the latter does not include the location of `gzip` on your system

Comment: @steeldriver I updated the question to include more information.

Comment: @VyomYdv what is the output of `whereis gzip`?

Comment: `$ whereis gzip
gzip: /usr/bin/gzip /usr/share/man/man1/gzip.1.gz /usr/share/info/gzip.info.gz`

Comment: It is working now, don't know what the problem is but yesterday, I added `export PATH="$PATH:......."` to `/etc/environment`, today I removed those statements and placed them in bashrc and zshrc files, that might be connected to it.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work that is why I added it to bashrc and zshrc

Comment: Yeah see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664301/65304